# Visual Studio 2010: Projectitem unavailable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

When trying to design a form in Visual Studio 2010:

[image]

How do i tell Visual Studio to ignore whatever's causing the problem and continue?

---

Research the problem showed two possible solutions:

- [Merideth was able to click "Ignore and Continue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090435/image-button-on-visual-studio-2010-c). (i have no such option)
- [Dan simply restarted Visual Studio (Visual Studio 2005)

In my case restarting Visual Studio causes it to get its head out of it's own assembler.

Someone phrase those in the form of an answer, and get free rep. ([SO prevents me from posting my own answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).

Comment: You can post your own answer - from your link: "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Comment: @StuartDunkeld: i was referring to the time delay.

Comment: There's a time delay? Sorry, I didn't know, and that page doesn't mention it. How long is it?

Comment: @StuartDunkeld Something like 2 minutes.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Simply restart Visual Studio, and it will get unstuck.

- It's a bug in Visual Studio.
- Microsoft isn't going to fix it.
- Microsoft isn't going to release the source code so anyone else fix it.
- Microsoft isn't going to even investigate the issue.

So we are where we are: you have to workaround their bugs.

Comment: Or you can just refresh and clean the solution too.

Comment: @BenDol i cleaned and rebuilt the solution but it did not fix , hopefully i restarted and it worked, this solution worth  vote up

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, it works but you don't have to restart VS, you can just unload / reload the solution or project.

Answer (score 2):

It may be contributed by using  the method  by this.variable() instead of varable();

Whenever the project is opened, the data in the instance is cleared and reset . The previous state of the instance may be lost. So , the warning is here.